# DriveApp.setSharing is now throwing an Exception, is there something wrong with the legacy runtime?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

The following code was working previously (and still works with the V8 runtime):

```
function myFunction() {
  var file = DriveApp.createFile("Test", "Test");
  file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.DOMAIN_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
  Logger.log(file.getUrl());
}
```

Now it is throwing the following error:

```
Invalid argument
```

I have isolated the issue down to the DOMAIN or DOMAIN_WITH_LINK Access parameter. PRIVATE works fine. ANYONE and ANYONE_WITH_LINK throws a permissions error (which is expected as this user does not have access to share outside the domain).

Unfortunately I cannot update the script to use the V8 runtime due to my use case.

One other thing to note: I get this exact same error with this exact same code when running it in a free Google account. (Could it be an issue with Google's engine recognizing the domain?)

Comment: Evidently there are several issues regarding sharing  161201634,150506089,36762368,36758868,36758912

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Cooper there are many issues regarding sharing.

The most recent issue is currently being worked on: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161201634

You just have to go there and click on the star next to the title so you get updates on the issue and you give the issue more visibility.

Comment: Thanks! This exactly answers my question. I am using the advanced Drive service as a workaround for the time being as it still functions properly with the Rhino runtime.